# Azure Mobile Client custom authentication unable to access controllers with [Authorize] attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, custom-authentication

I am using Azure Mobile Service Client with custom authorisation on `Xamarin.Forms` platform.

The login using `.LoginAsync("custom", user)` appears to work correctly in that it returns a `MobileServiceUser` with non-null `MobileAuthenticationToken` and `UserId` and automatically hooks up the `<MobileServiceClient>.CurrentUser` with that value.

However, whenever I attempt to make a further request (immediately on login) I get a `MobileServiceInvalidOperationException`..`(Unauthorized)` response, when I inspect the `CurrentUser` value - it is still the same.

Am I missing something with the `MobileServiceClient`? My understanding is that if it has a non-null value for `.CurrentUser` then it will include that in the headers as the `X-ZUMO-AUTH` header.

Server Login:

```
[Route(".auth/login/custom")]
public class AuthController : ApiController
{
    private readonly AppContext _context;

    private readonly string
        _singningKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY");

    private readonly string
        _audience;

    private readonly string
        _issuer;

    public AuthController()
    {
        _context = new AppContext();

        var website = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME");
        _audience = $"https://{website}/";
        _issuer = $"https://{website}/";
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] LoginUser body)
    {
        if (body?.Username == null || body.Password == null || body.Username.Length == 0 || body.Password.Length == 0)
        {
            return Request.CreateUnauthorizedResponse();
        }

        if (!IsValidUser(body))
        {
            return Request.CreateUnauthorizedResponse();
        }

        var claims = new[] { new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, body.Username) };

        var token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(claims,
                _singningKey,
                _audience,
                _issuer,
                TimeSpan.FromHours(24));

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new LoginResult
        {
            AuthenticationToken = token.RawData,
            User = new LoginResultUser() { UserId = body.Username }
        });
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool IsValidUser(LoginUser user)
    {
        .. this works fine
    }
}

public class LoginUser
{
    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class LoginResultUser
{
    [JsonProperty("userId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}

public class LoginResult
{
    [JsonProperty("authenticationToken")]
    public string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("user")]
    public LoginResultUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Client Login:

```
var database = new MobileServiceClient(BackendApiServerAddress);
var result = await database.LoginAsync("custom", JObject.FromObject(user)); //this sets database.CurrentUser to a MobileServiceUser with MobileAuthenticationToken and UserId and returns the value
await database.SyncContext.PushAsync(); // this fails
```

Exception:

```
{Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The request could not be completed.  (Unauthorized)
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<ThrowInvalidResponse>d__24.MoveNext () [0x001ec] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<SendRequestAsync>d__26.MoveNext () [0x000fc] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<RequestAsync>d__18.MoveNext () [0x000fa] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable+<ReadAsync>d__20.MoveNext () [0x000a3] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable+<ReadAsync>d__18.MoveNext () [0x00141] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.PullAction+<ProcessTableAsync>d__14.MoveNext () [0x0015c] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.TableAction+<ExecuteAsync>d__29.MoveNext () [0x002a5] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServiceSyncContext+<ExecuteSyncAction>d__34.MoveNext () [0x0008e] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServiceSyncContext+<PullAsync>d__30.MoveNext () [0x0039b] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at FRAOffline.Backend.Database.DbContext+<SyncCustomersAsync>d__32.MoveNext () [0x00049] in C:\Users\Heather\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\FRAOffline\FRAOffline\FRAOffline\Backend\Database\Customers.DbContext.cs:83 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, your custom authentication could validate the client user and generate the `authenticationToken` successfully. I would recommend you check the Authentication / Authorization settings and make sure Set the **Action to take when request is not authenticated** to **Allow Request (no action)** under the "SETTING > Authentication / Authorization" of your Azure Mobile App. Additionally, I would recommend you leverage [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network traces when invoking `await database.SyncContext.PushAsync()`. Moreover, you could also use postman to simulate the request against your table controller as follows to narrow this issue:

```
GET https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/tables/{table-name}
Header x-zumo-auth:{authenticationToken}
```

In addition, you could also follow adrian hall's book about [Custom Authentication](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/) and [Authentication in the Backend](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/backend/).

Comment: Thank you for these tips, I will see where I get

Comment: It was a problem with the Authentication / Authorisation settings. Thank you!